# Jboss Connection Pooling Configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

In my Jboss server, datasource is configured as following ( jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml).
Is connection pooling enabled here, if so then how many connections and how to track them.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/env/NVXDataSource" pool-name="NVXDataSource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nvx?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>admin</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

I am looking at defining following properties, where should i do that.

```
<min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size> 
<prepared-statement-cache-size>50</prepared-statement-cache-size>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Setting <xa-datasource-class> to a driver class is not a good idea. Especially when later using <datasource>.

Answer (score 4):

These are the property of connection pool. Add the following XML to the `<datasource>` element.

```
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
            </pool>
           <statement>
              <prepared-statement-cache-size>50</prepared-statement-cache-size>
          </statement>
```

Here is an example (from [official JBoss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration). )

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
  </datasources>

</subsystem>
```

[Here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7) is another supporting link.

Comment: thank you Santosh. enabled="true" is already there after pool-name="NVXDataSource", what does it signify ? if pooling is enabled ,then how many connections.Is there any way to track them. Coz before doing any modification i just want to know at what stage are they.

Comment: `enabled=true` signifies that the pool is to be created for usage. If the pooling is enabled and the pool is under use, then one way to track is to use the [JBoss console](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/Admin_Console_Guide/en-US/html/Administration_Console_User_Guide-Accessing_the_Console.html). All the connection pool implementations expose the pool status via a JMX  MBean. JBoss Console is the place where all the MBeans are available.

Comment: thanks Santosh. Any idea how many min/max connections will it create through enabled="true" , without defining any min/max-pool-size.

Comment: These defaults are dependent on the Connection Pool implementations. Please consult the relevant documentation.

Comment: On jboss7 it defaults to 20 connections.